# Como funciona o RewriteBase no .htaccess?

Tags: apache, htaccess, url-rewrite, mod-rewrite

Sempre usei o `.htaccess` para `url's amigáveis no php`, porém recentemente ao passar para o servidor de uma empresa X, o .htaccess que sempre funcionava não funcionou naquele servidor....

Depois de pesquisar descobri que era só colocar o `RewriteBase /` para ele funcionar...

Alguém poderia me esclarecer como esse `RewriteBase`funciona e como ele afeta o `mod_rewrite`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bem, o `RewriteBase` é uma diretiva que específica o prefixo da URL que será utilizada para substituir um caminho relativo, ou seja, você pode escrever um caminho base para suas `rewrites`. É bastante útil em situações em que o seu código não está no diretório root do servidor.

Este é um exemplo bem simples, retirado da [documentação do Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), que representa o funcionamento do `RewriteBase`.

```
<Directory /opt/myapp-1.2.3>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /myapp/
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$  welcome.html 
</Directory>
```

Neste caso o diretório `root` da aplicação não está no mesmo diretório do servidor, então com o `RewriteBase` você estará dizendo para o servidor que quando aquela rota for solicitada ele deverá executar a aplicação localizada na `/opt/myapp-1.2.3`.

Quanto ao `mod_rewrite`, é o módulo responsável por trabalhar com as regras de escrita das URL's amigáveis que serão definidas no `.htaccess`.

Comment: Nota: esse exemplo tem como pressupostos `DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com` e `Alias /myapp /opt/myapp-1.2.3`.